# Spring data - db to jms - how to set an already processed flag?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

New to Spring batch...

I have setup a Spring batch project that reads items from a database with a custom ItemReader, transforms them into XML with an ItemProcessor and puts them on a JMS queue in an ItemWriter.

```
<batch:job id="sendItemsToJMS" job-repository="myJobRepository">
    <batch:step id="sendItemsToJMSStep">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" 
                         processor="itemProcessor" 
                         writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="10">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

What needs to happen in the same transaction of a chunk is to flag the original items in the database as being sent.

Where would this logic go?  Do I need to setup an extra Tasklet in the same step, as seem to be suggested in the documentation (5.2.1. TaskletAdapter)

and if so:
- is it executed in the same transaction?
- how would I get the list of processed IDs in the tasklet?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void ItemWriteListener.afterWrite(List<? extends S> items)
```

> Called after ItemWriter.write(java.util.List) This will be called before any transaction is committed, and before ChunkListener.afterChunk(ChunkContext)

Implements this function and - inside - perform flag update.